# Finding expected value of position squared in quantum mechanics

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, definite-integrals, quantum-mechanics

I'm stuck on this question for a physics assignment

> 1. A particle in one dimension is prepared in a quantum state given by the wave function
>      $$\psi(x) = \left(\frac{\beta}{\pi}\right)^{1/4}\exp\left(-\beta x^2/2\right),\quad -\infty <x<\infty,$$
>      where $\beta> 0 $.
>      [**Given:** $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\, e^{-y^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\,y^2e^{-y^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$]

I'm looking for the expected value of the position squared for this waveform which is given by the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\psi^2 dx$ and I've rearranged it to get this 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\left(\frac{\beta}{\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\beta x^2}$$
but can't see how to progress. Does anybody have any tips/solutions?

Comment: This is a famous problem, the variance of a Gaussian distribution. You can reduce it to just the integral of the Gaussian distribution itself using integration by parts. The integral of the Gaussian distribution itself is then an even *more* famous problem, solved using a clever trick. However, you can do it even more easily, because you are given the answer for $\beta=2$ already. So you can just do a linear change of variable to reduce to the case you are given.

Comment: Please type out all images. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-\beta x^2}\mathrm dx\\
\stackrel{\text{by parts and u substitution}}{=}
\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{\pi}}xe^{-\beta x^2}\vert_{-\infty}^\infty+\frac{1}{2\beta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\beta x^2}\mathrm dx\\
=\frac{1}{2\beta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\beta x^2}\mathrm dx
$$
can you finish from here using the fact about the gaussian integral? The substitution $u=\sqrt{\beta}x$ looks pretty appealing...

Comment: Another approach is to take a $\beta$-derivative of the last Gaussian integral. (This works for any $x^{2n}$ if one takes $n$ derivatives.)